# How to help PyCharm discover tests after refactoring

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, testcase, automated-refactoring

Summary: After moving a file with a TestCase class in it (using refactor), tests are no longer executed at all.

I have a class startupTests.py that has:

```
import unittest
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

in it. I have a testcase class on the same level with multiple test. In the past I could simply run this `startupTests.py` class to execute all tests (including tests in other files on the same level). Here is another example file `test_example.py` with tests that were executed when I called `startupTests.py`

```
from unittest import TestCase


class TestValidateConfiguration(TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

I knew that I would write quite a few tests, so I decided to move `test_example.py` into another folder. I noticed that this somehow broke the connection between `startupTests.py` and `test_example.py`. The TestCases in startupTests.py were no longer executed when running startupTest.py

I can still execute the tests in `test_example.py` using the green arrow next to the code in the GUI. But they are no longer executed when running `startupTests.py`. I would like to - again - execute all tests in all test_files when running my main in `startupTests.py`

**What I have tried**

1. I moved the file back into the same folder, but still they are not
   executed. Therefore it is not the "you need an **init**.py file to
   discover" problem.
2. I created a second file with a TestCase, in order to see if the connection was just broken to the old file. Tests in the new file are also not executed.
3. I explicitly set PythonIntegratedTools>Testing>Default test runner to Unittests
4. I looked for visual changes in the code, but found none.

Comment: "I can still execute the tests using the GUI." So what kinds of tests are _not_ working? Tests on the command line?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I see that my issue was very implicit. I updated the question in order to make both the different files and my current issue more clear.